# search by document.contentType

Tags: solr

I am indexing document.contentType in my Solr core and want to know what the right syntax is to search by document.contentType. I want to get a list of, for example, all the document.contentType with the value application/pdf

Answer (score 0):

If your field is named `document.contentType`, querying the field directly by field name should work. Be advised that the general recommendation is to avoid anything other than alphanumeric characters and underscore in the field name.

```
q=document.contentType:application/pdf
```

.. or if escaping is necessary because of the `.`:

```
q=document\.contentType:application/pdf
```

You can retrieve all documents by querying for `*:*` to confirm that the values you're expecting are in the index.

Comment: ` I have tried q=document.contentType:application/pdf and q=document\.contentType:application/pdf but get no documents.  When I do `*:*`, I do see lots of pdfs and the field is returned as  "document.contentType":["application/pdf"] `